# Using Grape with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, ruby-grape

I am planning for an API app in Rails using Grape micro-framework. Is it a good idea to use Grape with Rails. Are there any prerequisites that I should take care of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on your long term goal of what you are planning to do with your API. If you want to make a stable API and maintain that for the long term use, I don't recommend grape (from my personal experience). I have used grape in one big project, and it was too hard to work with it when it comes to customizations e.g. handing exceptions etc. Instead you should consider using [ActiveModelSerializer](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers) or [jbuilder](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder). I personally moved to ActiveModelSerializer from Grape, and was happy at the end. grape is good for building your API quickly as it provides a decent DSL, but in the long run, it was hard to maintain and add new features and customizations. So, it really depends on your long term goal.